# Using CamlQuery in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, caml-query

I'm trying to write a `CamlQuery` that goes through all of the documents in the library and returns a list of docs that contain certain metadata tags.

I have a working version which recursively does this but it takes forever. However my Visual Studio project doesn't seem to notice the `using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;` import and therefore cannot find the `CamlQuery` reference.

Is there some other place I need to include this for it to be recognized?

**Code**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
public content getTopicDocs2(string meta)
{
    content returnContent = new content();
    List<doc> ReturnItems = new List<doc>();

    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPDocumentLibrary lib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["public"];

    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
    query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Topics'/><Value Type='Text'>" + meta + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
    ListItemCollection collListItem = lib.GetItems(query);
}
```

**Error**

> The type or namespace 'CamlQuery' could not be found

Comment: try by removing <view></view> and <query></query>, only keep <where></where >.

Comment: @karthik the error is at `CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First,** The above code is `Server-side object model`, not `Client Side object model` so you should use `Microsoft.SharePoint` not `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` namespace

**Second,** the `CamlQuery` is used with `Client Side object model` at `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` namespace.

**Third,** in `Server-side object model` you should use `SPQuery`  with `Microsoft.SharePoint`

**Fourth,** you can't use SSOM with CSOM!

**Fifth,**  the above code has a lot of error and will not work !!

**The Last thing,** to get items from doc library via SSOM check

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mySite/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    { 
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = "<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Topics'/><Value Type='Text'>" + meta + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
        SPList docLib = web.Lists["Shared Documents"];    
        SPListItemCollection files = docLib .GetItems(query);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
              try by removing CAMl Query query= new CAMLQuery(); and query in this way                                                                                                              
SPQuery Query= new SPQuery();                                                                              
Query.Query=qry;                                                                                 
string qry=@"yourcaml query   
           (or)                                                                                        


SPQuery query  =new SPQuery();                                                                   
query.Query = string.concat("<Where><Contains><FieldRefName='Topics'/<ValueType='Text'>" + meta + "</Value></Contains</Where>");
```